# How do I put a link to a webpage in a JScript Alert dialog box?

Tags: javascript, alert

I would like to put a link to a webpage in an alert dialog box so that I can give a more detailed description of how to fix the error that makes the dialog box get created.

How can I make the dialog box show something like this:

```
There was an error.  Go to this page to fix it.
wwww.TheWebPageToFix.com
```

Thanks.

Comment: Keng what can be a solution for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347654/combo-box-is-getting-vanished-when-an-alert-is-coming)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try asking them if they wish to visit via window.prompt:

```
if(window.prompt('Do you wish to visit the following website?','http://www.google.ca'))
  location.href='http://www.google.ca/';
```

Also, Internet Explorer supports modal dialogs so you could try showing one of those:

```
if (window.showModalDialog)
   window.showModalDialog("mypage.html","popup","dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");
else
   window.open("mypage.html","name","height=255,width=250,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,modal=yes");
```

Comment: Code will always get you props on my questions ;o)

Comment: rpetrich what can be a solution for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347654/combo-box-is-getting-vanished-when-an-alert-is-coming)

Answer (score 9):

You can't. Alert boxes don't support html. You should display the error as part of the page, it's nicer than JS alerts anyway.

Answer (score 6):

If you ***really*** wanted to, you could override the default behavior of the `alert()` function. Not saying you ***should*** do this.

Here's an example that uses the YUI library, but you don't have to use YUI to do it:

[YUI-based alert box - replace your ugly JavaScript alert box](http://htmlblog.net/yui-based-alert-box-replace-your-ugly-javascript-alert-box/)

Answer (score 6):

You can't - but here are some options:

- `window.open()` - make your own dialog
- Use `prompt()` and instruct the user to copy the url
- Use JavaScript to just navigate them to the url directly (maybe after using `confirm()` to ask them)
- Include a `div` on your page with a [FIX IT] button and unhide it
- Use JavaScript to put a fix it URL into the user's clipboard (not recommended)

Answer (score 2):

Or use window.open and put the [link there](http://qa.techinterviews.com/q/20060809080754AAs7gKM).

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could, `alert()` boxes are generally modal - so any page opened from one would have to open in a new window. Annoying!

Answer (score 2):

```
alert("There was an error. Got to this page to fix it.\nwww.TheWebPageToFix.com");
```

That's the best you can do from a JavaScript `alert()`. Your alternative option is to try and open a new tiny window that looks like a dialog. With IE you can open it modal.