# How to give href tag to p tag which is assigned to javascript how to give mailing functionality on clicking the href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function incorrectAuthentication() {

     var msg = "Please click the BACK button to return to the log-in screen. If you see the incorrect Personal Message after a second log-in attempt please contact  " + ' <a href="#"> info@hayscompanies.com </a> ' + " for assistance.";
    alert(msg);
    return false;
}
```

It displays all the text including href.
I have give the screen shot of alert.
How I will alert by giving href to 'info@hayscompanies.com' and mailing functionality on clicking it.

[image]

i do not have a page i can make only alert not popup and i have to include mailing functionality

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: @Jai: then please help me to implement the functionality

Comment: @josna You can use dialog api or go through the link which is caused in closing of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202/how-do-i-put-a-link-to-a-webpage-in-a-jscript-alert-dialog-box

Comment: i need the mailing functionality.And i have to get href inside the p tag.

Comment: Above given image is the the my requirement